# Ordenação de resultado pelo SQL dinamicamente

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, classificação, order-by

Primeiramente boa tarde,
Trabalho especificamente com Java no Back-end usando WebServices Rest e PostgreSQL, depois de alguns aprimoramentos profissionais fui orientado a passar ordenação e paginação de minha aplicação para o SQL, que sobrecarregaria menos o servidor da aplicação e o resultados retornariam de forma ágil.
Até então paginação não foi o problema, poderia utilizar o FETCH ou LIMIT para assim poder controlar, porém cheguei em um impasse quando fui avançar para ordenação. Usando CASE no ORDER BY em SQL não foi possível usar ele de forma dinâmica para ordenar colunas de tipagem diferente. Segue o exemplo:

```
SELECT
    a.idade,
    a.nome,
    a.cpf
FROM
    cadastro a
ORDER BY
(
    CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN
        a.idade
    WHEN 2 THEN
        a.nome
    WHEN 3 THEN
        a.cpf
    END
)
```

Este exemplo citado acima não executaria com sucesso pelas colunas não serem de mesmo tipo. E fazendo vários CASE não ficaria legal e produtivo de definir tantos parâmetros no Prepared do Java. Pedi na comunidade de SQL e me orientaram a fazer os scripts em funções e passar ordenação como parâmetro, mas não achei está forma muito atraente. Então pensei na formatação da String antes de passar para o Prepared, porém é suscetivo a SQL Injection e com toda certeza não vou querer arriscar essa opção.

Então peço dicas, agradeço desde já!

Obs.: Sobre terem mencionado [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132). Eu tentei fazer CASE em SQL igual citei acima e pensei na hipótese de montar o script na function e view, porém não é uma solução que agradou meu patrão, conversão dos tipos não funcionaria para todos casos de scripts do sistema, então estou procurando soluções alternativas. Concatenação de String antes de mandar para o PreparedStatement também já pensei, porém como evitar uma SQL Injection?

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que você está tentando fazer, mas me parece ser um caso de um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132). Não seria melhor você apenas montar 3 consultas SQLs distintas, uma ordenando por idade, uma ordenando por nome e uma ordenando por CPF e deixar a aplicação escolher qual dessas consultas será enviada ao banco de dados, conforme o caso?

Comment: tente SELECT
    a.idade,
    a.nome,
    a.cpf
FROM
    cadastro a
ORDER BY
(
    CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN
  lpad(a.idade, 3, '0')
    WHEN 2 THEN
        a.nome
    WHEN 3 THEN
        a.cpf
    END
)

Comment: A ordenação vem de acordo com a sequência dos campos por parâmetro? Não seria mais simples você passar o campo?

Comment: @VictorStafusa em meu ver poderia existir uma solução melhor que essa. Se todo script do sistema que eu for fazer ordenação server side eu fizer isso, vai ser não produtivo.

Comment: @Motta não é uma solução adequada, fazer conversão.

Comment: @KaranAlvesPereira PreparedStatment não aceita passagem de nome de coluna.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode "montar" a sua query utilizando um `StringBuilder`:

```
public String montarQueryConsulta( int ordem )
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("SELECT c.idade, c.nome, c.cpf FROM tb_cadastro AS c ORDER BY ");

    switch( ordem )
    {
        case 1:
            sb.append("c.idade");
            break;

        case 2:
            sb.append("c.nome");
            break;          

        case 3:
            sb.append("c.cpf");
            break;

        default:
            sb.append("");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

E depois, construir um `PreparedStatement` a partir da string montada:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( montarQueryConsulta(2) );
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Isso não seria uma brecha para uma SQL Injection?

Comment: @DorcílioNeto: Não no exemplo acima. A montagem da consulta por meio de um `StringBuilder` deve ser sempre feita com bastante cuidado para se evitar esse tipo de brecha. Não utilizar o `PreparedStatement` implica na filtragem individual de cada um dos parametros de entrada. Repare que na resposta o parametro de entrada `ordem` é tratado como um inteiro e de forma bastante restrita.

Answer (score 0):

Se você realmente quiser seguir por esse caminho você pode simplesmente fazer o cast (para varchar), assim você contornaria o problema das colunas serem de tipos diferentes.

Mas note que usar uma cláusula `CASE` dentro de uma cláusula `ORDER BY` não é muito performático.

Considere alterar isso para três consultas (ou talvez mesmo, para "reaproveitar código" criar uma view) e chamar cada query de acordo com a condição.

Comment: criar uma view e function, chegamos quase ao mesmo impasse. Meu patrão não curtiu muito essa solução.
E no caso como estamos fazendo paginação e ordenação server side, estou com esse problema nas mãos.

Comment: @DorcílioNeto Não uma function, apenas fazer o encadeamento de `IF`. No Postgres não sei como ele lida com isso. Em outros SGBDs cada query dentro de um `IF` tem sua própria query plan e melhora a performance. Usar um view seria opcional, uma boa opção se vc não quer reescrever a mesma query n vezes. Note claro que essa é uma solução boa quando vc tem poucas opções. No caso se vc tivesse 15 colunas o melhor seria apelas p/ queries dinâmicas parametizadas.Não vejo problema na paginação.

Comment: Vc pode escrever uma query genérica de paginação como uma SP e passar sua query como parâmetro (já fiz isso algumas vezes e geralmente o resultado é bom). Não ligue p/ oq o seu chefe diz a não ser que ele seja um bom desenvolvedor/engenheiro/dba. Quem vai dar manutenção nisso é vc.